# Python Pandas Date Index Series Date&Time converting to One TimeZone to Another Time Zone

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time

From external data source the below data is received and aligned.

```
                        open    high     low   close  volume
timestamp                                                  
2019-04-02 05:59:00  381.00  381.00  379.70  379.70       0
2019-04-02 05:58:00  380.90  380.90  380.85  380.85    5040
2019-04-02 05:57:00  380.85  380.95  380.65  380.95    9615
2019-04-02 05:56:00  380.60  381.20  380.60  381.00   13041
2019-04-02 05:55:00  379.80  380.60  379.80  380.60   19586
```

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

csvdata = StringIO("""timestamp,open,high,low,close,volume
2019-04-02 05:59:00,381.00,381.00,379.70,379.70,0
2019-04-02 05:58:00,380.90,380.90,380.85,380.85,5040
2019-04-02 05:57:00,380.85,380.95,380.65,380.95,9615
2019-04-02 05:56:00,380.60,381.20,380.60,381.00,13041
2019-04-02 05:55:00,379.80,380.60,379.80,380.60,19586""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",", index_col="timestamp", parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

# results
print( df)
```

This code is working fine for other calculation however ,the timestamp shown here is GMT-4 timestamp (Got to know from data provider).
I wish to convert this from one time zone to other time zone GMT-4 to GMT+5.30 .
Tried some option and it is failed showing "date" is not part of the index.How to make this as reusable code as converting from any timezone(Input time zone might be changing to UTC or GMT-2) to required timezone.

```
#fmt = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z"
#now.strftime('%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S')
#x.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z") #'2015-03-26T10:58:51'
fmt = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"
#keyupdate=key
dfdaily = pd.read_csv(dailyurl, index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])
#dfdaily['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfdaily['date'])
print(dfdaily.head(5))
dfdaily = dfdaily.rename_axis('date')
dfdaily= dfdaily.sort_index()
dfdaily.index.name = 'date'
print("Actual Time",dfdaily.index.strftime(fmt))
# Convert to US/Pacific time zone
now_pacific = dfdaily.index.astimezone(timezone('US/Pacific'))
print("Coverted US time",now_pacific['date'].strftime(fmt))
# Convert to Europe/Berlin time zone
now_india = now_pacific.index.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
print("India Time",now_india['date'].strftime(fmt))
return dfdaily
```

**Note :**when i debug and see the retreived data it shows 2019-04-02T0205:59:00.0000 but when i print  it comes as 2019-04-02 05:59:00 why ?
 print(dfdaily.head(5))

In the above code what should be the change i need to do to convert the timezone. Also for me the date Indexing did not working do not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is the input data.  Depending on certain things, the datetime data will load as 'naive' (IE no tz) or 'tz-aware'.  Given the MCVE in the above code, it is expected that the data loads 'naive'.  Check by looking at the initially loaded index.

`df.index.tz`

Once a dataframe is constructed with a `DateTimeIndex` Pandas can do the desired tz work.

In the following answer, note that the Olson TZ database is used for placenames in the GMT+X hours offset.  Here, GMT+5:30 is Asia/Kolkata.

Also, for any advanced manipulation of timezones and datetime types, the `pytz` library is practically required.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

csvdata = StringIO("""timestamp,open,high,low,close,volume
2019-04-02 05:59:00,381.00,381.00,379.70,379.70,0
2019-04-02 05:58:00,380.90,380.90,380.85,380.85,5040
2019-04-02 05:57:00,380.85,380.95,380.65,380.95,9615
2019-04-02 05:56:00,380.60,381.20,380.60,381.00,13041
2019-04-02 05:55:00,379.80,380.60,379.80,380.60,19586""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",", index_col="timestamp", parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

print("index type {}".format(type(df.index)))
# is tz 'naive'
print("index tz None is naive {}".format(df.index.tz))

# results
print(df)

# so give it a locale, since input data is naive, 
# UTC must be presumed unless there is additional
# input data not specified in above example
df.index = df.index.tz_localize("Etc/UTC")
# is tz 'naive'
print("index tz None is naive {}".format(df.index.tz))

# now that the DateTimeIndex has a tz, it may
# be converted as desired
random_tz = "Asia/Kolkata"
df.index = df.index.tz_convert("Asia/Kolkata")

# results
print(df)
```

```
index type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
index tz None is naive None
                       open    high     low   close  volume
timestamp                                                  
2019-04-02 05:59:00  381.00  381.00  379.70  379.70       0
2019-04-02 05:58:00  380.90  380.90  380.85  380.85    5040
2019-04-02 05:57:00  380.85  380.95  380.65  380.95    9615
2019-04-02 05:56:00  380.60  381.20  380.60  381.00   13041
2019-04-02 05:55:00  379.80  380.60  379.80  380.60   19586
index tz None is naive Etc/UTC
                             open    high     low   close  volume
timestamp                                                        
2019-04-02 11:29:00+05:30  381.00  381.00  379.70  379.70       0
2019-04-02 11:28:00+05:30  380.90  380.90  380.85  380.85    5040
2019-04-02 11:27:00+05:30  380.85  380.95  380.65  380.95    9615
2019-04-02 11:26:00+05:30  380.60  381.20  380.60  381.00   13041
2019-04-02 11:25:00+05:30  379.80  380.60  379.80  380.60   19586
```

Please accept is this answers the question.